# Serving multiple directory in one path/location with nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have been trying serve multiple directories in one location so that all files can be access on /sys/assets/--FILE-- regardless of where is the file physically locate in the following folder

```
location /sys {
    alias /var/www/website_api/sys/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /sys/index.php$is_args$args;
    location ~ \.php {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
        location /sys/assets {
           alias /var/www/website_api/sys/app/assets/javascripts/;
        }
        location /sys/assets {
           alias /var/www/website_api/sys/app/assets/stylesheets/;
        }
        location /sys/assets {
           alias /var/www/website_api/sys/app/assets/images/;
        }
}
```

Goal:

```
/sys/assets/javascriptFile.js
/sys/assets/stylesheetFile.css
/sys/assets/image.png
```

Comment: Get rid of this and use `try_files`.

Comment: Do you have an example

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have duplicate prefixed locations in your configuration. However, that's possible to do what you expect using `try_files` directive :

```
location /sys {

    alias /var/www/website_api/sys/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /sys/index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/sys/assets/?(.*)$ {
        root /var/www/website_api/sys/app/assets;
        try_files /javascripts/$1 /stylesheets/$1 /assets/images/$1;
    }

}
```

If you absolutely need to spare inappropriate filesystem lookups (i.e. kernel `stat()` calls under Linux), you can also do it more precisely using multiple regex locations matching suitable file extensions :

```
location /sys {

    alias /var/www/website_api/sys/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /sys/index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/sys/assets/?.*\.css$ {
        rewrite '^/sys/assets/(.*)$' '/$1' break;
        root /var/www/website_api/sys/app/assets/stylesheets;
    }

    location ~ ^/sys/assets/?.*\.(gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svg)$ {
        rewrite '^/sys/assets/(.*)$' '/$1' break;
        root /var/www/website_api/sys/app/assets/images;
    }

    location ~ ^/sys/assets/?.*\.js$ {
        rewrite '^/sys/assets/(.*)$' '/$1' break;
        root /var/www/website_api/sys/app/assets/javascripts;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to serve files from several different roots, try using named locations.

```
    location / {
        root "E:\Directory1";
        try_files $uri $uri/ @dir2;
        index  index.php;
        autoindex on;
    }
    location @dir2 {
        root "F:\Directory2";
        index  index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

Set autoindex on the first one and 404 on the last one (as shown). Should be able to chain as many as you wish. You can also do the same thing for your `.php` location.

Comment: Two years later I come across my own answer when looking up this question again. Thank you, StackExchange.

Comment: This will show only the contents of the first directory in the user-facing directory listing, right?

Comment: > nginx: [emerg] the "alias" directive cannot be used inside the named location